# MUI: The value found in theme for prop: "error" is an [Object] instead of string or number

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In MUI v5.14.13, everything was working fine and all of sudden I started getting the following error:

```
MUI: The value found in theme for prop: "error" is an [Object] instead of string or number. Check if you forgot to add the correct dotted notation, eg, "background.paper" instead of "background".
```

Which seems to be coming from `style.js:34` file. Even though there is no direct use of styled component in that component, I am getting the above error message.

##### Here is an example

The below code will start a dialog box in full screen and close it when clicked cancel:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import CloseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";
import Slide from "@mui/material/Slide";
import { Box, Button, Stack } from "@mui/material";

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
  return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

const FullScreenDialog = ({ open, onClose }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        fullScreen
        open={open}
        onClose={onClose}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
      >
        <AppBar sx={{ position: "relative" }}>
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              edge="start"
              color="inherit"
              onClick={onClose}
              aria-label="close"
            >
              <CloseIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Box margin={{ sm: 3, xs: 2 }}>
          <Stack spacing={1} direction="row" justifyContent={"flex-end"}>
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              color="error"
              size="small"
              onClick={onClose}
              sx={{
                borderRadius: 10,
                textTransform: "none",
                ":hover": {
                  bgcolor: "error",
                  color: "error",
                  border: "error",
                },
              }}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </Stack>
        </Box>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FullScreenDialog;
```

When clicking on `Cancel` button, the same error is coming. And even when click on the start button from a different component, still the same error is coming.

Any idea is anything has changed in MUI which is causing this issue ?

Comment: Hi. please share your code.

Comment: @alivarastepour  I have added a code snip.

Comment: I get similar warnings for other props too, like `body1` and `action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a regression in this version of Material UI, and it's been resolved in [this pull request](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/pull/39457) which should be included in the next version that'll be released in the next day or two.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Today they released MUI v5.14.14 and after upgrading to that version, the issue has been resolved.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!